# Doing Uniswap v3 swaps with native ETH

Tags: ethereum, swap, uniswap

What would be the address if I want to swap tokens from ETH?

```
ISwapRouter.ExactOutputSingleParams memory params =
            ISwapRouter.ExactOutputSingleParams({
                tokenIn: TOKEN_IN_ADDRESS,
                tokenOut: TOKEN_OUT_ADDRESS,
                fee: poolFee,
                recipient: msg.sender,
                deadline: block.timestamp,
                amountOut: amountOut,
                amountInMaximum: amountInMaximum,
                sqrtPriceLimitX96: 0
            });

        amountIn = swapRouter.exactOutputSingle(params);
```

In this case, what would be TOKEN_IN_ADDRESS if I want to use native ETH?

Comment: You can use uniswap Auto Router which will convert native `ETH -> WETH` automatically and will do the swap for traders.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, you cannot, Uniswap V3 explicitly assumes you are using WETH, nor does it perform any automated wrapping like V2 did, you must wrap your own ETH and provide the WETH address as an input.

Answer (score 1):

In Uniswap v3, you can use Ether natively instead of wrapping it to WETH. When you input ETH into the `exactInputSingle` or `exactOutputSingle` method, Uniswap will automatically wrap the ETH to WETH and then swap it for the desired token, before returning the result in the output token.

`amountOut = swapRouter.exactInputSingle{value: amountIn}(params);`

For Mainnet use WETH9 contract:
`TOKEN_IN_ADDRESS = 0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2`

Proove: https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-periphery/blob/main/contracts/base/PeripheryPayments.sol#L58

Answer (score 0):

```
ISwapRouter.ExactOutputSingleParams memory params =
            ISwapRouter.ExactOutputSingleParams({
                tokenIn: TOKEN_IN_ADDRESS,
                tokenOut: TOKEN_OUT_ADDRESS,
                fee: poolFee,
                recipient: msg.sender,
                deadline: block.timestamp,
                amountOut: amountOut,
                amountInMaximum: amountInMaximum,
                sqrtPriceLimitX96: 0
            });

        amountIn = swapRouter.exactOutputSingle(params, {value: amountIn);
```